# Selecting column tied to a max column

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm using Salesforce Marketing Cloud and looking to create a table that holds each subscriber and details about that sub's last engagements.

Existing code pulls the subscriber and their last open or click alright, but I need to link to another table for the email's name.

Table structures are:

```
SUBSCRIBER
+---------+---------------------+
| SubID   | EmailAddress        |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | joe@test.com        |
|       2 | jane@test.com       |
+---------+---------------------+

OPENS
+---------------+------------+--------+
| EmailAddress  | EventDate  | JobID  |
+---------------+------------+--------+
| joe@test.com  | 03/04/19   | 1      |
| joe@test.com  | 03/05/19   | 2      |
| joe@test.com  | 03/06/19   | 3      |
| jane@test.com | 03/06/19   | 3      |
+---------------+------------+--------+

CLICKS
+---------------+------------+--------+
| EmailAddress  | EventDate  | JobID  |
+---------------+------------+--------+
| joe@test.com  | 03/04/19   | 1      |
| joe@test.com  | 03/05/19   | 2      |
| joe@test.com  | 03/06/19   | 3      |
| jane@test.com | 03/06/19   | 3      |
+---------------+------------+--------+

JOB
+-------------------------------+
| JobID  | EmailName            |
+--------+----------------------+
| 1      | Spring Sale          |
| 2      | You Are Missing Out  |
| 3      | Please Help          |
+--------+----------------------+
```

My goal is to update the Subscriber table with this info:

- What the last engagement date was
- Whether that engagement was an email Open or a Click
- What the name of the email was

My current SQL is:

```
SELECT
  s.[EmailAddress] AS 'EmailAddress',
  CASE  
    WHEN c.EventDate < o.EventDate THEN o.EventDate
    ELSE c.EventDate
  END AS 'LastEngagedDate',
  CASE  
    WHEN c.EventDate < o.EventDate THEN 'Open'
    ELSE 'Click'
  END AS 'EngagementType'
FROM Subscriber s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT EmailAddress, MAX(EventDate) AS 'EventDate'
  FROM _Click 
  GROUP BY EmailAddress) c ON c.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT EmailAddress, MAX(EventDate) AS 'EventDate'
  FROM _Open 
  GROUP BY SubscriberKey) o ON o.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress
```

Obviously, this leaves out the Email name. The problem that I'm running into is getting the appropriate JobID tied to the MAX(EventDate) for both _Click and _Open so that I can join the JobID to the _Job table to pull the appropriate Email Name.

Let me know if I can clarify this problem further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic row_number() like this:

```
FROM Subscriber s
    left join
            (SELECT EmailAddress, EventDate, JobID    
             row_number() over(partition by EmailAddress order by EventDate desc) rn
            FROM _Click ) c on c.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress and c.rn=1
```

Note `c.rn=1` in the join `ON` condition. Only record with max date will be joined and all columns are available. And the same for Open events.